# What is needed to use Vagrant with Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, vagrant

I've set up vagrant as described in [the docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/hyperv).

When running `vagrant up` I get the following message:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'hyperv' provider...
==> default: Verifying Hyper-V is enabled...
The Hyper-V cmdlets for PowerShell are not available! Vagrant
requires these to control Hyper-V. Please enable them in the
"Windows Features" control panel and try again.
```

While I understand the message, I feel this is not the underlying issue.
I did

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

and the following reboot.

`Get-VM` lists all my machines. So I feel the Hyper-V cmdlets should be installed and usable.

This is running on Windows 10 20H2, Vagrant version is 2.2.14, Hyper-V PowerShell module version is 2.0.0.0

What am I missing here?

Edit:

Installed Hyper-V Features are:

[image]

PowerShell version:

```
> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.610
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.610
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

I have also cross-posted to [discuss.hashicorp.com](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/what-is-needed-to-use-vagrant-with-hyper-v/20941)

Edit 2

The error is coming from [`\Vagrant\embedded\gems\2.2.14\gems\vagrant-2.2.14\plugins\providers\hyperv\scripts\check_hyperv.ps1`](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/57842d7269cdb1e86b2eef696b6232b0ae4eef7f/plugins/providers/hyperv/scripts/check_hyperv.ps1) which essentially does `Get-Command "Hyper-V\Get-VMSwitch"` and if that fails reports the error.

Now, my system seems to be unable to load `Hyper-V\Get-VMSwitch` without some "help":

```
❯ get-command "Hyper-V\Get-VMSwitch"
get-command : The term 'Hyper-V\Get-VMSwitch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-command "Hyper-V\Get-VMSwitch"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Hyper-V\Get-VMSwitch:String) [Get-Command], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand

❯ get-command "Get-VMSwitch"

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-VMSwitch                                       2.0.0.0    Hyper-V


❯ get-command "Hyper-V\Get-VMSwitch"

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-VMSwitch                                       2.0.0.0    Hyper-V
**strong text**
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of **Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online** with a screenshot and include it in the body of your question

Comment: @Ramhound all of it? I have added a screenshot of the ones starting with `Microsoft-Hyper-V`

Comment: PowerShell 5.1 or PowerShell 7.1? (within the same prompt that you ran vagrant up)

Comment: @Ramhound 5.1 - I updated the question. (But I also checked in 7.1 just now. Also, no joy.)

Comment: Try to specify the provider explicitly : `vagrant up --provider hyperv`.

Comment: @harrymc yields exactly the same result as above. Does specifying the provider explicitly make a difference to having the provider in an environment variable?

Comment: Once it helped, but not in your case. Is everything ticked under *Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off > Hyper-V*?

Comment: @harrymc as seen in the PowerShell screenshot above, all Features of Hyper-V are installed.

Comment: Vagrant worked first with VirtualBox and only later with Hyper-V. Perhaps it has problems with the latest Windows 10 version. You might then need to fall back to VirtualBox. I don't know if [HashiCorp Support](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011134227-Engaging-with-HashiCorp-Support) is available for you, but you may ask the [Community](https://www.vagrantup.com/community).

Comment: You might be missing: `Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V-PowerShell`.

Comment: @harrymc `Install-WindowsFeature` is a command for Windows Server and does not exist on Windows 10. On Win10 the equivalent would be `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell` which is enabled (see "Installed Hyper-V Features" above)

Comment: That's true. For my money, what you have left is either tracking the problem via the Vagrant user forums, or give up Hyper-V and use VirtualBox. Perhaps someone else will have some other advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the Vagrant installation was done correctly and according to
the documentation. I can't see anything wrong, and all comments were
answered by the poster.

My conclusion is that Vagrant with Hyper-V has a problem under the latest
Windows 10 upgrade.

The options I see are:

- Wait for a correction release from Vagrant
- Address the problem to
  [HashiCorp Support](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011134227-Engaging-with-HashiCorp-Support)
  (unlikely to get an answer), or to the
  [Vagrant Community](https://www.vagrantup.com/community)
- Vagrant has worked first with VirtualBox before it did with Hyper-V,
  and most likely is still working well on it.
  You might need to fall back temporarily to VirtualBox while waiting for
  a Hyper-V solution (which will likely be more performant).

Comment: You're missing one option (I'll accept regardless - because you kept on pushing me to try other things :-) ) - I found the problem last night and it was on my machine: I (probably I, who else...) broke the `$env:PSModulePath`. Somehow `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` was no longer part of that. After adding it back in, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

*To have the whole picture here I'll add one additional answer:*

After much trying and checking other machines for cross-referenct it boiled down to `Import-Module Hyper-V` not working on my machine, while at the same time `Get-VMSwitch` would implicitly load the Hyper-V module.

This brought me eventually to `$env:PSModulePath`, which on two (!) of my machines looked like this:
[image]

(notice the `System.String[]` at the end) while on newly installed machines it contained `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` (and not the `System.String[]` rubble)

So. Changing `PSModulePath` environment to look like this:
[image]

fixed the whole problem.